# what's the meaning of "true to the old proverb"?

Tags: meaning

> I will certainly tell you, Socrates, what my own experience of it is. I and a few other people of my own age are in the habit of frequently meeting together, **true to the old proverb**. On these occasions, most of us give way to lamentations, and regret the pleasures of youth, and call up the memory of amours and drinking parties and banquets and similar proceedings. - The Republic of Plato

What's the meaning of **true to the old proverb**? I couldn't find **the old proverb**.

Comment: I think there is some **old proverb** in which it says something like "*people of my own age are in the habit of frequently meeting together*"

Comment: @SovereignSun Ah.. maybe.. I missed the proverb. BTW "true to" means "the proverb is true"?

Comment: Consider this: http://www.dictionary.com/browse/true-to

Comment: Consider that this is a translation from a text written in ancient Greek. So it would be a Greek proverb.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the source (and the obscure *reference* within it) is ancient Greek, not current English. There's no particular reason why an average Anglophone would know anything about the particular ancient Greek proverb being referenced *in an ancient Greek text*.

Comment: Well, the phrase "true to the old proverb" is English, and understanding that it refers to an absent-but-presumed-understood proverb is part of understanding English. The follow-up details are more about Greek, it's true.....

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This phrase indicates that a proverb is being fulfilled, although not directly cited. (You didn't miss it; it does not appear in this text.) The idea is that the reader will recognize the situation and recall the proverb. The situation is "true to" the proverb, meaning that it shows the truth of the proverb.

If the context were modern English, the old proverb would probably be, "Birds of a feather flock together," meaning that people tend to associate with those who are similar to themselves. Indeed, some translators of The Republic allude to this proverb in the quoted passage.

In this case, we need a proverb that was common in Athens around the time of Socrates: "ἧλιξ ἥλικα τέρπει". It translates roughly as, "two of the same age delight each other", and it appears directly in another of Plato's dialogues, The Phaedrus.

Comment: The "birds of a feather one" came to my mind as well, but of course Socrates doesn't know it. Very nice reference to the Greek one the speaker probably had in mind!

Comment: The information contained here is hardly relevant to the needs of people learning *English* - but it's obviously spot-on, so +1